# Was there any specific attire for the chazzanim?

Tags: clothing, chazzan-prayer-leader

I know that today in many Ashkenazi synagogues chazzans wear eight-panel hats (borrowed from Catholic Christianity?) and satin robes.

Were there other and earlier types of vestments?

Comment: What makes you think it was taken from Chrisitianity?

Comment: @Dov I saw exactly the same hats with Catholic priests. Until now, these are worn by Ukrainian Greek-Catholic priests.

Comment: I'm unclear about your focus here -- your title asks in the past tense (was there) then the question moves to a present tense statement, assuming that what is worn by some is somehow codified. Why do you think that there is specific attire which is satisfied by the hat and robe? Plenty of chazzanim pray without those. Even the concept of "chazzan" is relatively recent.

Comment: Yes but whose to say they didn't get it from the Jews e.g. the Kohen Gadol wore a mitznefes and a regular Kohen wore a migba’as.... i.e. A ceremonial hat was part of the Temple service for many years prior....

Comment: Are you referring to Reform synagogues? Much of the early opposition to Reform was because they changed the synagogue services to resemble churches. I never heard of an Orthodox shul doing this. Generally the only thing someone who is Chazzan would wear is a tallis.

Comment: https://www.thejewishinsights.com/wp/tag/benzion-miller/  First name that came to mind. Orthodox chazzanim wear it as well

Comment: https://www.oztorah.com/2012/03/robes-the-rabbis/